# QuickSort in Python - explain the behavior of the implementation using list comprehension

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort

I have a function called quickSort() that does just that. I am trying to understand the behavior of the 'smaller' and 'larger' lists (see below). Specifically, how does Python deal with memory when using recursion within a function? Each time the function is called, do the 'smaller' and 'larger' lists get overwritten (I'm assuming this happens...)? If so, where does the extra memory get released, as each function execution the lists will get smaller...

```
def quickSort(lst):
   if len(lst) <= 1: 
      return lst
   smaller = [x for x in lst[1:] if x < lst[0]]
   larger = [x for x in lst[1:] if x >= lst[0]]
   return quickSort(smaller) + [lst[0]] + quickSort(larger)
```

What exactly happens with the two lists that are created, and if there is any benefit in using an in place sort in this scenario.

Disclaimer: I am a novice at Python and algorithms in general, detailed explanations will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the question rephrased:

Starting with the initial list, `[8,5,2,9,1,7,3,4,6]`
quickSort #1 produces 3 lists: `[5,2,1,7,3,4,6] , [8] , [9]`
quickSort #2 produces 3 lists: `[2,1,3,4] , [5] , [6,7] (plus [8] , [9])`
quickSort #3 produces 5 lists: `[1] , [2] , [3,4] and [6] , [7] (plus [8] , [9])`
quickSort #4 produces 1 list: `[1] , [2] , [3] , [4] , [5] , [6] , [7] , [8] ,[9]`

They are all concatenated in the process. What I am wondering is whether the lists `[8,5,2,9,1,7,3,4,6] , [5,2,1,7,3,4,6] , [8]` and so on are stored until the program exits. (The implementation above might not be correct, I just want to illustrate my point).

Comment: Each function call gets its own stack frame that has its own local variables. There is no relation between the local variable `smaller` between calls

Comment: The memory (for each stack level's locals) will not get released until the function (at that stack level) completes. This means you're using NlogN extra space. If that's a problem, you can do things like breaking up that expression at the end into separate lines and then del or clear the values earlier, or you can, as you suggested, sort in-place instead of to a copy, but they all come with disadvantages (starting with not being as readable as the simple version you started with).

Comment: By the way, what I just wrote is only true for CPython. A different implementation like PyPy or Jython might not release the lists until even later (the next time the garbage collector runs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick sort is **O(nlogn)**, it continuously cuts the problem into halves as you will see is what this problem does.

Assuming a list **x** and calling `quickSort(x)`

```
x = [6,12,4,5,2,5,14,23,1,5]
quickSort(x)
```

This is a recursive function, from within itself it will call the function again. However, each call of the function has its own stack, it does not have access to variables outside its scope.

Ok so on the initial call of this function, `smaller` and `larger` will store lists associated with the values smaller than, and larger than, the first value in the list.

```
smaller = [4, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5]
larger = [12, 14, 23]
```

This split is done through list comprehension. We go through each value in the list except the first value. If the current value being evaluated is less than the first value in the list, then we will add it to the `smaller` list. We then do the same for the `larger` list.

Now the return function is

```
return quickSort(smaller) + [6] + quickSort(larger)
```

---

Let's do the smaller side first.

```
quickSort([4, 5, 2, 5, 1, 5])

lst[0] = 4
smaller = [2, 1]
larger = [5, 5, 5]

return quickSort(smaller) + [4] + quickSort(larger)
```

---

So this process continues until we reach a point where `len(lst)<=1` and the recursion unravels backwards. Imagine a new branch of a tree extending each time the function is called. When the function finally returns the values propagate back up the tree. The end result is a sorted array.

> [1, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 12, 14, 23]

Comment: I understand what the algorithm does, just not fully grasping the memory implications. I'm thinking of arrays of pointers in C++ and trying to see if a memory leak can occur in Python when the `smaller` and `larger` lists aren't overwritten using the same memory locations, but allocated new ones for each function execution.

Comment: No, the lists will not get overwritten from within a function.

Comment: So the total amount of memory used for the quickSort function will depend on the number of function calls? Like, say, the function is called three times for the `smaller` list and twice for the `larger` list, are all these lists that are created (plus the initial, unsorted list) stored in memory until the sorting is done?

Comment: Yeah the stack is retained in memory until the return is complete. I think the code can be made clearer by changing the return statement to be like this `temp = quickSort(smaller) + [lst[0]] + quickSort(larger)` and then `return temp`. Now we can see that the line that calls the functions isn't returning yet, these are being called from within a function. So, 2 new stacks are being created for `smaller` and `larger`. Then the function only returns after those two subcalls are returned.

Comment: that makes much more sense. Also see edit above, I want to learn more about exactly what happens to discuss this with my professor in a somewhat educated fashion... Thanks

Comment: @YuriyF: There's no memory leak, because the memory is being tracked (with internal reference counts in CPython, by a different garbage collector in most other Python implementations). But the memory is not actually free until the top-level function returns. So, you have O(log N) stack frames, each of which has local variables (the two lists) holding O(N) data. Does that make sense?

Comment: @abarnert That is exactly the answer I am looking for... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think [JahKnows's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227868/908494) explains almost everything you want, and more concisely than I ever could, but a few more points that you seemed to be unclear on.

---

First, you were worried about a "memory leak". There's no memory leak here, because Python uses a garbage collector to automatically figure out what to delete. The CPython implementation (the one you're probably using) uses explicit internal reference counting: as soon as your last reference to an object (a local variable, a list element, an object attribute, etc.) goes away, the object gets deleted and its memory is freed. Since you're familiar with C++: this is like every value being wrapped in a `shared_ptr`. Other implementations use fancier (more efficient, but less deterministic) collectors, but still, they can't delete anything that you still have references to.

In particular, each recursive call to `quickSort` has its own local variables `lst`, `smaller`, and `larger`. You don't `del` those anywhere, or assign new values to them, so they don't go away until the function call completes. And the function call can't complete until the two recursive calls it makes have completed.

So, you have `O(log N)` recursive "frames" at any given time, each of which has `O(N)` local storage, so the total space being used is `O(N log N)`.

---

You asked whether there's an advantage to doing things in-place, and the answer is: yes. It's more complicated (and has some other drawbacks), but if you sort in-place, and you're just mutating bits of a single list that you pass down and back up the stack, you avoid the `O(N log N)` space cost (plus some `O(N)` time cost, but since the total time is `O(N long N)`…).

---

Can you avoid the space cost without switching to in-place? Well, unless you can destructure the list as you're recursing (which is difficult—and in that case, why not just do it in-place?), you obviously need at least `O(N)` space for any copying sort. And `O(N log N)` isn't that much worse than `O(N)`. But we can improve things.

For example, consider this:

```
def quickSort(lst):
   if len(lst) <= 1: 
      return lst
   smaller = [x for x in lst[1:] if x < lst[0]]
   larger = [x for x in lst[1:] if x >= lst[0]]
   lst0 = lst[0]
   del lst # lst is freed up now
   smaller = quickSort(smaller) # original smaller freed after this
   larger = quickSort(larger) # original larger freed too
   return smaller + [lst[0]] + larger
```

But this is obviously more complicated, and easier to get wrong. And it may even be slower. Is it worth it? Well, if you really need a copying quicksort, and the extra memory being used is pushing the edge of 32-bit crashes or driving you into 64-bit swap hell, then yeah. Otherwise, probably not.